# calling perl WWW::Google::PageRank from java ProcessBuilder API

Tags: java, perl, pagerank

I need to be able to programmatically find the PageRank of a site from java. I couldn't get anything I found in java to work, but this perl module looked promising. Here is some documentation for the perl
[http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Google::PageRank](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aGoogle%3a%3aPageRank)

The only experience with Perl I have is calling a perl script from java once before...

I wrote this script and placed it in the resources folder of my java project.

```
#file: pr.pl
use WWW::Google::PageRank
$loc=<>;
$gpr=WWW::Google::PageRank->new();
print $gpr->get($loc);
```

when I type http://www.google.com at the command line after invoking the script, I get this message back: HHTP::Response=HASH(0x1d41554)

Can anyone tell me whats going on? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ykar/WWW-Google-PageRank-0.17/lib/WWW/Google/PageRank.pm) they print the page rank this way.

```
print scalar($gpr->get($loc)), "\n";
```